# How to delete jobs in Azure data lake analytics

Tags: azure-data-lake

Hey i'm beginer with Azure datalake , i have created some jobs in azure datalake analytics, now i want to delete them, can any one tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Lake Analytics jobs that are submitted cannot be removed from the job history. You can cancel the job before it completes, but it will be logged in the history as well.

I recommend that if you want to run jobs locally, you use Visual Studio with the Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio. You can see more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-local-run

Let us know if you have more questions.

Thanks!